# Hardrive problem (slow reads and writes) Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, io

Recently I built a new box with i7 cpu 6Gb of ram and SAMSUNG Spinpoint F3 HD103SJ 1TB 7200 RPM 32MB Cache SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5"

The new box is running Ubuntu 10.04 64Bit and use xfs filesystem

Old one is Ubuntu 7.10 32Bit and ext3 filesystem

I noticed that this powerful machine I built runs slower than my 3yrs old box when it comes to IO intensive tasks. For example when I run simpletest (testing framework) on my codebase it takes 3-5 more time on the new box..

Is there a way I can try to pin point this problem and make sure that hardive is a problem (or not).

I did run bonnie++ test on both boxes:

Old - http://pastebin.com/VDuv2EjB New box - http://pastebin.com/Laq8tGAd

When I was comparing 2 reports I spotted big difference in Sequential IO Per Chr section.

What can cause such a difference and is it the indicator of the potential problem?

I hope to hear some suggestion and recommendations for further debugging..

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found out:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1717652

> When I change the /tmp of the host OS from EXT4 to EXT3, my vmbuilder builds the same VM in less than 4 minutes! (instead of more than 12 minutes)

I guess it's the EXT4?

Comment: This should either be extended or converted to a comment.

Comment: Thanks for ext4 related info. Was a good read. I don't use it though in favor of xfs and maybe xfs is a problem.. Will have to benchmark I guess.